# What are Concurrency Conflicts?

Tags: concurrency

What are Concurrency Conflicts with regards to SQL database?

Comment: You may want to check this article: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0607081

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you have an SQL statement, e.g., `UPDATE table SET a = a + 1 WHERE ...`, which would correspond to the following code:

```
read a
a = a + 1
write a
```

Assume that two clients A and B execute this simultaneously. The following could happen (time flows from top to bottom):

```
   A           B
read a     
            read a
a = a + 1
write a
            a = a + 1
            write a
```

What happens? `a` is incremented only once, although it should have been incremented twice. This is a classical concurrency conflict. To avoid such conflicts, databases use **transactions** and **locks**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that transaction isolation problems (e.g. non-repeatable read, phantom read, dirty read) are at least part of what you are looking for. See more e.g. here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency Conflicts occur when two transaction try to lock one resource at the database.There are many tutorials on this just use google to find some.Here is link to one
[link text](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/concurrencyControl.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried google, got the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd937753(SQL.105).aspx, but couldn't understand what the concept was. Your link is a bit more helpful. Thanks